# change or deactivate iOS 9 newsfeed on the search screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 5 and just updated to iOS 9 (all german).

What I really do not like is the content of the newsfeed that is presented to me on the search screen. How can I change what content is presented to me (no more news from spiegel.de or focus.de please!) or if that is not possible, how can I completely disable news on that search screen but keep all the rest of the proactive search features on that search screen?

It appears in the US locale, the [solution is to disable the news app from contributing to spotlight search](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206080/3293) but this app (and the switch for it) does not exist in iOS 9 that detects a german locale.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the detail about this being a non-US locale issue. It would stink if Apple QA missed adding the news toggle for you to suppress spotlight search. It was the first thing I turned off to make Siri suggestions useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it by navigating to `Settings` > `General` > `Spotlight Search`
This will however disable the whole news feed and other Spotlight Search feed items such as:

- recent applications
- recent contacts
- nearby places

When you scroll down the `Spotlight Search` settings, please check out the "About Spotlight Suggestions & Privacy..." link on the bottom.
This will contain a lot of information about what information is sent from your phone to Apple and third parties like Microsoft when you open or use Spotlight Search.
This information includes among other things: search queries, location, account names, subscription information.

More information about Spotlight Search can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201285).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the news from appearing in the search page by going to: Settings->General->Spotlight search, then disable Spotlight suggestions.

Comment: I wonder what other suggestions except the news-suggestions will also be disabled by turning off this flag.